# Font Family does not work in Android 11 (api 30)

Tags: android

**font family does not work on Android 11** (api 30) and all the apps that have font family in my phone have become the default font of the phone.
If you have this problem and there is a solution, thank you.

I use this:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_name</item>
```

This does not work either:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_name</item>
<item name="fontFamily">@font/font_name</item>
```

Comment: can you show more details

Comment: What information do you want Vatsal kesarwani?

Comment: Show some sample code you are working on.